# gulp-uglify creates wrong output

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify, gulp-useref

I'm trying to run a task to minify and other stuff in my index.html:

```
gulp.task('bundle', function(){
    var assets = useref.assets();
    var autoprefixerConfig = {
        browsers: ['last 2 versions', '> 4%', '> 4% in BR'],
        cascade: false
    };

    return gulp.src('src/*.html')
        .pipe(assets)
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', autoprefixer(autoprefixerConfig), minifyCss()))
        .pipe(assets.restore())
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(minifyHtml())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

But all javascripts (like bootstrap.js, respond.js...) appear to be wrong in output files.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest break the task in single ones like for example one for minify js, one for minify html so it's easier to debug as well. You can specify dependency of a task using an array as second argument of the task and the callback as a third argument.

Comment: I do agree with @mitogh, have separate task for javascript minification and another one for css... and use those as dependency for your final task

Answer (score 0):

I created an individual task for minifyHtml and this solved the problem.

Thanks to @mitogh and @entre